# How to send the data from jquery ajax post() to node API

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

Client Side

```
    $('#Unit_Series').on('change', function (e) {

        var seriesid = $(this).val();
        console.log(seriesid);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/",
        data: seriesid,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
        })
    })
```

Server Side

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.data)
});
```

I am not getting the data to my server from client.

then i need to place the data to sql query to list a data from db to post it back to html select option.

Comment: Please console.log of req after check which key have data ??

Comment: If you're code exists in the same domain (localhost:3000) as your node.js server, you don't have to define the full url. Simply put "/" in the url. If you are using express in your node.js server, you can use `res.json(YOUR_DATA)` inside the .post('/') function to respond back to the client side.

Comment: ..also you dont set `data` anywhere

Comment: ...and its `req.body` for POST's

Comment: Yes Mr. @LawrenceCherone i dont set data any where in server.. but i dont not how to recieve data from jquery post method and pass on to a var called data in my server

Comment: to check my ajax post request is working when the change event occurs. It is not showing even a console log message i think in ajax req itself i am going wrong some where

Answer (score 0):

I Got the Solution

Ajax Req

```
$('#Unit_Series').on('change', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var seriesid = $(this).val();
        console.log(seriesid);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:3000/",
            method: "POST",
            data: { id: seriesid },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
    })
```

Server.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var cont = req.body.id
    console.log(cont);
    res.send(cont);
});
```